# How to get objects that have children of some type using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, children

How to get objects that have children of some specific type using jQuery? For example, having the next DOM:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Item 3
    <ul>
      <li>
        Item 3.1
        <ul>
          <li>Item 3.1.1</li>
          <li>Item 3.1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

How can I get all the `<li>` elements inside `#menu` that have at least one child of type `<ul>`?

Comment: `$('#menu li ul').parent();` ?

Comment: Could be for this specific example, but what happens if `<ul>` has a parent that is not an `<li>` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
$("#menu li:has('ul')")
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Working Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/V6Eqm/

Comment: First valid answer, first selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$('#menu li').has('ul')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FZTU9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use:

```
$('#menu li ul').parent();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vshzh/